# Python's select.select equivalent in Java

Tags: java, python

I've been socket programming in Python for an assignment using `select.select(rfile, wfile, xlist[, timeout])` to attend to requests made by a list of client sockets that are connected, and I also want to program in Java, and was looking for an equivalent to this select class that I could use in Java, but I couldn't find any and so I've decided to ask here. Can somebody tell me an equivalent or something similar that I could use?

Comment: btw, if you're down-voting, tell me a reason why so I could improve my questions in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it written [here](https://pymotw.com/2/select/) `select()` returns three new lists, containing subsets of the contents of the lists passed in. `readable list`, `writable list`, `exceptional list`. Java doesn't have multiply return and parallel assignment, basically this is an answer.

Java doesn't have such amount of high-level build-ins as Python does. In every Python module we can find some opportunities that will take hundreds of lines in Java to repeat.

Answer (score 0):

you can get select()-like behaviour by using Java NIO Channels... Java Implements Selector class, and channels (SelectableChannels) suscribe to it. A Channel can be a SocketChannel or another stream-like object that extends SelectableChannel Class.

Just like python's select(), Selector will use operating system's io interfaces in order to monitor streams/file descriptors.

A gentle introduction can be found here:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-nio-selector